# How to convert UTC to EST with Python and take care of daylight saving automatically?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

If I have a bunch of data with date & time in `UTC format`, how can I convert them to `EST`.

It can determine when they will be `-4(in summer)` and -`5(in winter)` automatically every year? 
Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You'll need to use the `pytz` module (available from PyPI):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = pytz.utc
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

winter = datetime(2016, 1, 24, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
summer = datetime(2016, 7, 24, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)

print(winter.strftime(fmt))
print(summer.strftime(fmt))

print(winter.astimezone(est).strftime(fmt))
print(summer.astimezone(est).strftime(fmt))
```

which will print:

```
2016-01-24 18:00:00 UTC+0000
2016-07-24 18:00:00 UTC+0000
2016-01-24 13:00:00 EST-0500
2016-07-24 14:00:00 EDT-0400
```

The reason why you'll need to use `'US/Eastern'` and not `'EST'` is exemplified in the last two lines of output.

Comment: Is "winter =" and "summer =" for setting whether it's summer or winter time for a specific date? If yes, it's impossible to do if I have over 10000 different dates. Also, every year is different, do we need to find out the exact date for the time change every year to use this method?

Comment: No, winter and summer is only variable names to point out that one date is in January and the other in July.

Comment: Thanks! your answer is great help!

Answer (score 9):

If you have a pandas series with object datatype, you can first convert it into a DateTime series using [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(your_series, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors ='coerce')
```

Check if it is timezone aware or not by using [series.dt.tz](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz.html)

```
df[col].dt.tz
```

If it's not timezone aware, we should make it timezone aware by using [series.dt.tz_localize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html). Also, do read about the ambiguous and nonexistent parameters of this function

```
df[col] = your_series[col].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
```

Now convert this series into the required timezone by [series.dt.tz_convert()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html)

```
df[col] = your_series[col].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

The above method will take care of daylight savings time. If you want to check more timezones you can pip install pytz and

```
import pytz
pytz.common_timezones
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you just want the normalized hour offset for your existing timedelta shifting:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def curr_est_offset():
    tz_est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    offset = tz_est.utcoffset(datetime.utcnow())
    offset_seconds = (offset.days * 86400) + offset.seconds
    offset_hours = offset_seconds // 3600

    return offset_hours # -4 or -5
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("your_data_file_path.csv", index_col=False, engine='python')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.replace(x, tzinfo=None))
```

What the last row does is removing the timezone info from the datetime object, so you can operate with the date and time only (don't worry, that doesn't change the timezone again, it just strips it from the timestamp string).

Answer (score 0):

This is thebjorn's answer converted from Python 2 to **Python 3** with a few additional comments.  Thanks to thebjorn.

For convention, I use these terms:

- **EST**: Eastern Standard Time (winter)
- **EDT**: Eastern Daylight Time
  (summer)
- **EPT**: Eastern Prevailing Time (standard or daylight saving
  time as appropriate)

**Code**:

```
# Convert EPT / UTC
import pytz
import datetime from datetime as dtdt
# Timezones
ept = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = pytz.utc
# str format
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

print("\nEPT/UTC examples:")
print("\nWinter (EST) example:")
# Create a UTC time in the winter
winter_utc = dtdt(2016, 1, 24, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
print("    UTC: ", winter_utc.strftime(fmt))
# Convert from UTC to eastern prevailing time.  Since, the timestamp is in the
# winter, prevailing time is standard time.
winter_ept = winter_utc.astimezone(ept)
print("    EPT: ", winter_ept.strftime(fmt))
# Let's convert back to UTC to show we get back to the original value.
winter_utc2 = winter_ept.astimezone(utc)
print("    UTC: ", winter_utc2.strftime(fmt))

# Let's do that again for a summer datetime.
print("\nSummer (EDT) example:")
summer_utc = dtdt(2016, 7, 24, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
print("    UTC: ", summer_utc.strftime(fmt))
# Convert from UTC to eastern prevailing time.  Since, the timestamp is in the
# winter, prevailing time is daylight saving time.
summer_ept = summer_utc.astimezone(ept)
print("    EPT: ", summer_ept.strftime(fmt))
# Let's convert back to UTC to show we get back to the original value.
summer_utc2 = summer_ept.astimezone(utc)
print("    UTC: ", summer_utc2.strftime(fmt))
```

**Console**:

> ```
> EPT/UTC examples: 
>
> Winter (EST) example:
>     UTC:  2016-01-24 18:00:00 UTC+0000
>     EPT:  2016-01-24 13:00:00 EST-0500
>     UTC:  2016-01-24 18:00:00 UTC+0000 
>
> Summer (EDT) example:
>     UTC:  2016-07-24 18:00:00 UTC+0000
>     EPT:  2016-07-24 14:00:00 EDT-0400
>     UTC:  2016-07-24 18:00:00 UTC+0000
> ```