# How to convert datetime to the right format to use the pytz module

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, pytz

If I have a bunch of datetime(UTC) in a column like this:

```
63058    01/22/2018 11:00:00
63059    01/22/2018 12:00:00
63060    01/22/2018 13:00:00
Name: date, Length: 63061, dtype: object
```

or this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2007-12-21 17:00:00', '2007-12-21 18:00:00',
           '2007-12-21 19:00:00', '2007-12-21 20:00:00',
           '2007-12-21 21:00:00', '2007-12-23 20:00:00',
           '2007-12-23 22:00:00', '2007-12-23 23:00:00',
           '2007-12-24 00:00:00', '2007-12-24 01:00:00',
           ...
           '2018-01-22 04:00:00', '2018-01-22 05:00:00',
           '2018-01-22 06:00:00', '2018-01-22 07:00:00',
           '2018-01-22 08:00:00', '2018-01-22 09:00:00',
           '2018-01-22 10:00:00', '2018-01-22 11:00:00',
           '2018-01-22 12:00:00', '2018-01-22 13:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=63061, freq=None)
```

How can I convert the whole (list or series), whatever it's called to this format:

```
datetime(2016, 1, 24, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
```

Because I need to use the `pytz` module to convert utc to eastern time.

I get this error: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'astimezone'` when I use `astimezone().strftime()` with my original data format.  [This is what I originally wanted to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416511/how-to-convert-utc-to-est-with-python-and-take-care-of-daylight-saving-automatic), but now I encounter this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function to convert one of the string representations as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def date_from_string(s):
    "Convert ``s`` from a string to a datetime object in the UTC time zone."
    dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

then you can use it with `map` in your constructor

```
DatetimeIndex(map(date_from_string, [
       '2007-12-21 17:00:00', '2007-12-21 18:00:00',
       '2007-12-21 19:00:00', '2007-12-21 20:00:00',
       '2007-12-21 21:00:00', '2007-12-23 20:00:00',
       '2007-12-23 22:00:00', '2007-12-23 23:00:00',
       '2007-12-24 00:00:00', '2007-12-24 01:00:00',
       ...
       '2018-01-22 04:00:00', '2018-01-22 05:00:00',
       '2018-01-22 06:00:00', '2018-01-22 07:00:00',
       '2018-01-22 08:00:00', '2018-01-22 09:00:00',
       '2018-01-22 10:00:00', '2018-01-22 11:00:00',
       '2018-01-22 12:00:00', '2018-01-22 13:00:00']),
      dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=63061, freq=None)
```

The docs have more info:

`datetime.strptime(..)`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

`map(..)`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Problem solved. I have a resampling problem, see if you can help. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428968/how-to-convert-1h-ohlc-data-into-weekly-with-a-specific-time-using-python