# How to convert time from UTC to EST?

Tags: python, timestamp, timezone

I have got a dataframe like this:

```
          dt                  |  value
2019-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC |  49.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00 +0000 UTC |  39.8
2019-01-01 02:00:00 +0000 UTC |  23.4
2019-01-01 03:00:00 +0000 UTC |  45.3
```

This timestamp is in UTC timezone, but I would like to convert it to EST. Here was my attempt:

```
dtobj = pd.to_datetime(data['dt'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Z')
dtobj = dtobj.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('US/Eastern'))
```

but it has the following error:

> TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'

I didn't find a clear answer to explain why this error happened. Are there any other ways to convert the timezone?

Comment: Are you [Seeking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197411/5929910) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dt.tz_convert`:

```
>>> df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Z')
>>> df['dt'] = df['dt'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
>>> df
                         dt  value
0 2018-12-31 19:00:00-05:00   49.0
1 2018-12-31 20:00:00-05:00   39.8
2 2018-12-31 21:00:00-05:00   23.4
3 2018-12-31 22:00:00-05:00   45.3
>>>
```

Comment: I tried and it showed AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @Cyan You also have to use the first line

Comment: @Cyan Or try: `df['dt'] = df['dt'].tz_convert('US/Eastern')`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the pytz module (available from PyPI):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = pytz.utc
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

dateTimeUtc= datetime(2016, 1, 24, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
dateTimeUtc.astimezone(est).strftime(fmt)
```