# How to convert from UTC to EST in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone, data-conversion

**Issue:** I have a python dataframe column `df['startDate']` that is a series of UTC timestamps. I'm trying to convert them all to Eastern (EST) timestamps in a new column `dt['startDateEST']`. For some reason everything I've tried outputs `df['startDateEST']` as an exact copy of `df['startDate']` (timestamps remain in UTC). Please help!

**I've tried:**

```
df['startDateEST'] = pd.Series(df['startDate']).dt.tz_convert(tz = 'American/New_York')

df['startDateEST'] = pd.Series(df['startDate']).dt.tz_convert(tz = 'US/Eastern')
  
df['startDateEST'] = df['startDate'].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, yearfirst=True).tz_convert('American/New_York'))

df['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startDate'], utc=True) 
df['startDateEST'] = pd.Series(df['startDate']).dt.tz_convert(tz = 'American/New_York')
```

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416511/how-to-convert-utc-to-est-with-python-and-take-care-of-daylight-saving-automatic

Comment: `df['startDate'].dt.tz_convert('American/New_York')` should be the way to go. If that doesn't work, please add a [mre] to demonstrate the problem.